# flickr.auth.getToken Invalid Signature

Tags: javascript, html, flickr

I'm try to get `authToken` from `flickr rest api` but console.log occured an error `Invalid signature` . My respone link is:
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.auth.getToken&api_key={apiKey}&frob={frob}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_sig={ApiSig} . Before i do request `frob` and `ApiSig` have been calculated.

```
ApiSig = MD5(secret+'api_key'+apiKey+'frob'+frob+'formatjsonmethodflickr.auth.getTokennojsoncallback1');
```

P.S.: `frob` is calculated correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this question. Parameters in URL must be in alphabetical order.